# Issue with composer install/update

Tags: laravel-4, composer-php

I'm working with a project made with Laravel 4 Framework, then I used this command to install the composer.

composer install

This is the execution result:

```
$ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing psr/log (dev-master 5144da9)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/lexer (dev-master 57d5a02)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/annotations (dev-master 97b4a00)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/collections (dev-master bcb5377)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/cache (dev-master ff36d42)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/inflector (dev-master 8b4b3cc)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/common (dev-master ba2ad8a)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/process (2.3.x-dev b09d36a)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/finder (2.3.x-dev fc0fbd5)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/console (2.3.x-dev f77c13a)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/filesystem (dev-master c136348)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/routing (2.3.x-dev 7d41463)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/debug (2.3.x-dev 93f2633)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (2.3.x-dev 30b2f95)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/http-foundation (2.3.x-dev 8ee2965)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/http-kernel (2.3.x-dev e6f1920)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing kriswallsmith/assetic (v1.1.2)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing codesleeve/sprockets (dev-master 2d14c76)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/dom-crawler (2.3.x-dev 7a72398)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v5.0.3)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing predis/predis (0.8.x-dev 09cb667)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing patchwork/utf8 (v1.1.16)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing nesbot/carbon (1.7.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing monolog/monolog (dev-master 5ad421d)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing nikic/php-parser (dev-master 0353c92)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing jeremeamia/superclosure (1.0.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing ircmaxell/password-compat (1.0.x-dev 1fc1521)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing classpreloader/classpreloader (1.0.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/translation (2.3.x-dev 6b255d2)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/css-selector (2.3.x-dev 8df20c5)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/browser-kit (2.3.x-dev 7149642)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing filp/whoops (1.0.7)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/dbal (2.4.x-dev ad8608b)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing laravel/framework (4.0.x-dev 426c9e0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing leafo/scssphp (v0.0.7)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing coffeescript/coffeescript (1.3.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing leafo/lessphp (v0.4.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing nitra/php-min (dev-master f2d5e3f)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing codesleeve/asset-pipeline (dev-master cad206e)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing mustache/mustache (v2.4.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing way/generators (dev-master 8390ef9)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Installing barryvdh/laravel-migration-generator (dev-master 5cd7ec3)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing dinesh/barcode (dev-master 6cbcffb)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/class-loader (dev-master d122b8a)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing dflydev/markdown (dev-master 6baed9b)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock (2.0.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper (v1.7.1)
    Loading from cache

symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/config ()
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/yaml ()
symfony/event-dispatcher suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection ()
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/config ()
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection ()
kriswallsmith/assetic suggests installing twig/twig (Assetic provides the integr
ation with the Twig templating engine)
kriswallsmith/assetic suggests installing ptachoire/cssembed (Assetic provides t
he integration with phpcssembed to embed data uris)
kriswallsmith/assetic suggests installing leafo/scssphp-compass (Assetic provide
s the integration with the SCSS compass plugin)
predis/predis suggests installing ext-phpiredis (Allows faster serialization and
 deserialization of the Redis protocol)
patchwork/utf8 suggests installing lib-icu (Use Intl for best performance)
monolog/monolog suggests installing mlehner/gelf-php (Allow sending log messages
 to a GrayLog2 server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-amqp (Allow sending log messages to an A
MQP server (1.0+ required))
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-mongo (Allow sending log messages to a M
ongoDB server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing doctrine/couchdb (Allow sending log messages
 to a CouchDB server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing raven/raven (Allow sending log messages to a
 Sentry server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ruflin/elastica (Allow sending log messages
to an Elastic Search server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing aws/aws-sdk-php (Allow sending log messages
to AWS services like DynamoDB)
symfony/translation suggests installing symfony/config ()
symfony/translation suggests installing symfony/yaml ()
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","me
ssage":"Class 'Codesleeve\\AssetPipeline\\Filters\\CssRewrite' not found","file"
:"C:\\laravel-projects\\plansherpa\\app\\config\\packages\\codesleeve\\asset-pip
eline\\config.php","line":64}}Script php artisan optimize handling the post-inst
all-cmd event returned with an error



  [RuntimeException]
  Error Output:



install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-p
lugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--ver
bose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader]
```

On OSX (Mountain Lion) and Windows 7 Home Premium shows me the same error message. How can I fix it now?

Please help me! Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have an issue with Laravel, not Composer, because everything Composer did went well - with the exception of calling the Laravel script that does some things. I learned that Laravel has some update procedure for recent versions (not using it myself) - you should check whether or not this procedure applies to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a codesleeve issue not laravel / composer.

Have you previously installed codesleeve?

Try removing that line from the app/config/app.php file

Remove codesleeve from composer.json

Run a composer update. Everything should be working now.

Re-add codesleeve to composer.json

Run another composer update

Re-add the codesleeve service provider to app/config/app.php

Run a composer dump-autoload

See how that goes with each step. I'm assuming the problem will still exist but the first 3-4 steps will be good.

Possibly look into upgrading laravel to 4.1 as I think the new codesleeve requires some stuff from this?

tl:dr its looking for Codesleeve\AssetPipeline\Filters\CssRewrite but cant find it.

Comment: Thank you very much! I could fix it by following the steps you gave me, and running the command `php artisan config:publish codesleeve/asset-pipeline` before re-adding the codesleeve service provider to app/config/app.php